# How to compare two text files with value in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, compare, text-files, readlines

I have two text file, and they have one same field(pet). I want to combine two file and output a new file contain three fields(owner pet buyer). My code is mainly depends on if both file have the same pet(name and number of pets) than I will add the name of buyer to the field of buyer in the new file. It should print out only if the two file have same filed of pet.

But my code did not work as I want, need some help, thanks.

input_file_1 (.txt)

```
owner pet
Michael dog, cat
John pig, rabbit
Marry dog, cat
```

input_file_2 (.txt)

```
buyer pet
Sean cat, dog
Mark cat, dog
Joy dog, mouse
Tina cat, dog
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
owner pet buyer
Michael cat, dog Sean, Mark, Tina
Mary cat, dog Sean, Mark, Tina
```

My code looks like this:

```
input_file_1 = ARGV[0]
input_file_2 = ARGV[1]

hash_1 = {}
File.readlines(input_file_1, "\n").each do |line|
  owner, pet = line.chomp.split("\t")
  hash_1[owner] = pet
end

hash_2 = {}
File.readlines(input_file_2, "\n").each do |line|
  buyer, pet = line.chomp.split("\t")
  hash_2[buyer] = pet
end

hash_1.each do |key, value|
  if hash_2.has_value? value
    puts "#{key}\t#{value}\t#{hash_2[key]}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a difference between "cat, dog" and "dog, cat"? What does that mean? Also, you split on the "\t" character, but where does it appear in your input files? Only after the name of the owner/buyer, or also between the "cat," and "dog"?

Comment: yes, both of my file are already sorted as A-Z. The "\t" character appear after the owner/buyer, "cat," and "dog".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use the `pet` as key:

```
input_file_1 = ARGV[0]
input_file_2 = ARGV[1]

hash_1 = Hash.new([])
File.readlines(input_file_1, "\n").each do |line|
  owner, pet = line.chomp.split("\t")
  hash_1[pet] += [owner]
end

hash_2 = Hash.new([])
File.readlines(input_file_2, "\n").each do |line|
  buyer, pet = line.chomp.split("\t")
  hash_2[pet] += [buyer]
end

hash_1.each do |pet, owners|
  if hash_2.include? pet
    owners.each do |owner|
      puts "#{owner}\t#{pet}\t#{hash_2[pet].join(", ")}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: by the way, what does += means here?

Comment: The values in the hashes are arrays. To add an item to the array I add an array with a single item to the current array in the hash: `a = [1];a += [2];a #=> [1,2]`